# Question on induction-1 is the least positive integer

Tags: induction

#### Question on induction

> prove: 1 is the least positive integer.

#### proof:

Let $A=\left\{x\geq 1\left|x\in Z^+\right.\right\}$, and then $1\in A$, if positive integer $n\in A$, then $n\geq 1$,

Since $1\leq n<n+1$, so $n+1\in A$. By induction, we have $A=Z^+$. So for all positive integer that it is greater than or equal to $1$, and $1$ is the least positive integer.

#### question:

There is something different from the induction pattern

$\text{when } n=1,\text{...}n=k,\text{...}\text{and } n=k+1,\text{...}$

So, can you explain me a bit more about the proof and the corresponding of the pattern I listed?

> I saw this as one first example in the first section of first chapter of one text of mathematical analysis. So I do not know the definition of "integer".

Comment: At this level you need to be very careful to define all of your terms and operations. In particular, how *exactly* are you defining addition, and how are you defining $\le$?

Comment: I agree with dfeuer - for that matter, how are you defining "integer"? How are you defining "positive"?

Comment: Then the question, as stated, just can't be answered. Please delete your two last comments—they are redundant.

Comment: @dfeuer can you understand the proof? Is it right in your sensation?

Comment: I don't understand this at all. Can you post it verbatim as in your book?

Comment: No, HyperGroups. Without the necessary definitions I have no idea what any of it is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slight rewording of the given proof in the induction format that you're used to:

> **Claim:** For all $n \in \Bbb{Z}^+,~$ $n\ge 1$.

**Proof:** We proceed by induction on $n \in \Bbb{Z}^+$.

**Base Case:** For $n=1$, we have $1 \ge 1$, which works.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that the claim is true for $n=k$, where $k$ is a positive integer. That is, assume that $k\ge 1$.

It remains to prove the claim true for $n=k+1$. Since $k \in \Bbb{Z}^+$, we know by the definition of the positive integers that $k+1\in \Bbb{Z}^+$. Recall that $k+1>k$. But by the induction hypothesis, we know that $k\ge1$. Hence, $k+1\ge1$, so the claim is true for $n=k+1$. This completes the induction.